# WCF hosted in WPF and how can i change control in MainWindow UI from wcf?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, wcf

I write WCF code and hosted in my WPF app.
I write class to switch my MainWindow to show other page in my project

```
public static class Switcher
    {
        public static MainWindow pageSwitcher;

        public static void Switch(Page newPage)
        {
            pageSwitcher.Navigate(newPage);
        }       
    }
```

and I write my wcf service like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IAppManager
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void DoWork();
        [OperationContract]
        void Page1();
        [OperationContract]
        void Page2();
    }
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
    public class AppManager : IAppManager
    {

        public void DoWork()
        {
        }
        public void Page1()
        {
            MainWindow.pageSwitcher = new MainWindow();
            MainWindow.Switch(new Page1());
        }
        public void Page2()
        {
            MainWindow.pageSwitcher = new MainWindow();
            MainWindow.Switch(new Page2());
        }
    }
```

I want change page remotely from another computer with WCF but it not work 
and I trace code the wcf is run and response but do not do anything 
how can access to main thread to change ui page or other element?

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense an is insufficient for solving your problem.

Comment: hi sorry I try again : I write WPF application and I hosted in this application wcf service . I want change mainwindow remotely for example I have 3 page in my application I want changing page show remotely with wcf from another computer and with another application like navigation control to change page view

Comment: Sorry, but this current implementation of yours is so bad that it's hard to know where to start. You can host WCF in WPF, but you cannot use WCF to show WPF (not directly). I would suggest you look at something like [Prism for eventing](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/355473/Prism-EventAggregator-Sample), and your main window can then subscribe to events and navigate in response to them.

Comment: thanks for your answer , do you have another solutions for me? I want show coustom content in mainwindows remotely like play video ,show news and weather, slide and more , I want this like signage(digital display)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current solution is unusual, but WCF can be hosted in a WPF application. However you should never try to directly manipulate the UI from the WCF service - you'll have cross thread issues to begin with.

What you should consider doing is using messaging via a pub-sub broker (image linked from MSDN):

[image]

Something that fits this bill nicely is [Prism's EventAggregator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx). A couple of samples I cherry picked are [*Simplifying PRISM’s EventAggregator*](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/simplifying-prisms-eventaggregator/) and [*Prism EventAggregator Sample*](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/355473/Prism-EventAggregator-Sample).

The way you use this is the service registers events and then raises them, the WPF subscribes to those events and processes them. With this you can also specify whether to receive the events on the UI thread or a [background thread](http://richarddingwall.name/2010/06/24/background-event-handling-in-prism/).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you start over and this time separate the WCF from your WPF app.

You need to:

1) Separate WCF from WPF - should be in different layers.

2) Use WCF with duplex binding - this way your WCF service will be able to communicate with clients when it needs to.

3) In your WCF callback contract (implemented by the client) - you should prepare a method that will be used to change the local UI mode.

Duplex binding is the perfect solution for your needs.

You can reed about Duplex [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Hope I helped!
Eking.